# Cannot pass struct to template function

Tags: c++, templates, vector, struct

So I'm trying to create a sorting function that takes in an `std::vector` and `struct` and sorts the vector based on the struct. My code for the function is this:

```
template<typename T, typename C> void sort(vector<T> &array, C &comp) {
    vector<T> blank(array.size(), 0);
    mergeSort(array, blank, 0, array.size() - 1, comp);
}
```

The .cpp file is this:

```
#include "array.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Compare {
    bool operator()(const string &first, const string &sec) {
      return first.size() < sec.size();
    }  
};

int main() {
    vector<string> str = {"aa", "a", "aaa"};
    Compare comp;
    vec::sort(str, comp);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I tried this and many, many other variations of this code, but all of them end in error. This particular one says `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error' what():  basic_string: construction from null is not valid`.

The full code for `"array.h"` is this:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;


/*
* Provides many algorithms and functions used with std::vector's
* @author M. Farnsworth
*/
namespace vec {

    /*
    * Sorts an std::vector either ascending or descending depending on ltog (least to greatest).
    * If ltog is false it sorts the std::vector in descending.
    * Is a proxy function between the user and the actuall sorting function.
    * Implements the merge sort algorithm.
    */
    template<typename T> void sort(vector<T> &array, bool ltog = true);

    /*
    * Sorts an std::vector based on the 'comp' given to it.
    * Is a proxy function between the user and the actuall sorting function.
    * Implements the merge sort algorithm.
    * Overloads the first 'sort'.
    */
    template<typename T, typename C> void sort(vector<T> &array, C &comp);
    
    /*
    * Second function in merge sort.
    * Can be called by user directly, they will just need to provide values for the rest of the parameters.
    * Don't call this function, call arr::sort(vector<int> &array, bool ltog) to sort.
    */
    template<typename T, typename C> void mergeSort(vector<T> &array, vector<T> &blank, int bottom, int top, C &comp);
    
    /*
    * Third function in merge sort.
    * Shouldn't be called by the user.
    */
    template<typename T, typename C> void merge(vector<T> &array, vector<T> &copy, int bottom, int half, int top, C &comp);
    
    /*
    * Swaps items at the indices 'first' and 'second' of the given std::vector.
    */
    template<typename T> void swap(vector<T> &array, int first, int second);

    /*
    * Reverses the order of the items in an std::vector.
    */
    template<typename T> void reverse(vector<T> &array);

    /*
    * Writes the items in an std::vector to an std::ostream.
    * Essentially this means it will display the array.
    * If called with only the std::vector it will display to the console or 'cout' by default.
    */
    template<typename T> void display(vector<T> &array, string diliminator = " ", bool endline = true, ostream &out = cout);

    /*
    * Provides a structor for comparing two T.
    * operator() returns true if first is less than second.
    * operator() returns false if first is greater or equal to second.
    * Used in 'merge' to sort an std::vector in ascending order.
    */
    template<typename T> struct SortLess;

    /*
    * Provides a structor for comparing two T.
    * operator() returns false if first is less than second.
    * operator() returns true if first is greater or equal to second.
    * Used in 'merge' to sort an std::vector in descending order.
    */
    template<typename T> struct SortGreater;

    template<typename T> struct SortLess {
        bool operator()(T &first, T &second) {
            return first < second;
        }
    };

    template<typename T> struct SortGreater {
        bool operator()(T &first, T &second) {
            return first > second;
        }
    };

    template<typename T> void sort(vector<T> &array, bool ltog) {
        vector<T> blank(array.size(), 0);
        if (ltog) {
            SortLess<T> comp;
            mergeSort(array, blank, 0, array.size() - 1, comp);
        } else {
            SortGreater<T> comp;
            mergeSort(array, blank, 0, array.size() - 1, comp);
        }
    }

    template<typename T, typename C> void sort(vector<T> &array, C &comp) {
        vector<T> blank(array.size(), 0);
        mergeSort(array, blank, 0, array.size() - 1, comp);
    }

    template<typename T, typename C> void mergeSort(vector<T> &array, vector<T> &blank, int bottom, int top, C &comp) {
        if (top != bottom) {
            int half = bottom + (top - bottom) / 2;
            mergeSort(array, blank, bottom, half, comp);
            mergeSort(array, blank, half + 1, top, comp);
            merge(array, blank, bottom, half, top, comp);
        }
    }

    template<typename T, typename C> void merge(vector<T> &array, vector<T> &copy, int bottom, int half, int top, C &comp) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            copy[i] = array[i];
        }
        
        int firstCount = bottom;
        int secCount = half + 1;
        int count = firstCount;
        
        while (firstCount <= half && secCount <= top) {
            if (comp(copy[firstCount], copy[secCount])) {
                array[count] = copy[firstCount];
                firstCount++;
            } else {
                array[count] = copy[secCount];
                secCount++;
            }
            count++;
        }
        
        for (int i = firstCount; i <= half; i++) {
            array[count] = copy[i];
            count++;
        }
        
        for (int i = secCount; i <= top; i++) {
            array[count] = copy[i];
            count++;
        }
    }

    template<typename T> void swap(vector<T> &array, int first, int second) {
        int temp = array[first];
        array[first] = array[second];
        array[second] = temp;
    }

    template<typename T> void reverse(vector<T> &array) {
        int len = array.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < ceil(len / 2.0); i++) {
            swap(array, i, len - 1 - i);
        }
    }

    template<typename T> void display(vector<T> &array, string diliminator, bool endline, ostream &out) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            out << array[i] << diliminator;
        }
        if (endline) out << endl;
    }
    
    template<typename T> void shuffle(vector<T> &array) {
        srand(time(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            int k = rand() % (i + 1);
            swap(array, i, k);
        }
    }


};
```

So my question is two-fold:

1. Why does the comp not work in main, but does int the other sort function?
2. What can I do to make this work as I intend?

Comment: The title is completely different from the question. You passed the struct to the template function. You get runtime error.

Comment: `vector<T> blank(array.size(), 0);` is problematic when `T` is `std::string`. The error you get is quite explicit.

Comment: I see that know. The reason I thought the problem was in the struct was because when every I changed that it threw an error.

Comment: Do you suggest I change the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
vector<T> blank(array.size(), 0);
```

Here you try to create a `vector<string>` with the size `array.size()` - but the `std::string` that you want to use for copying into the new `vector` is `0`, which is interpreted as a `const char*` - and it tries to read from that place in memory with *undefined behavior* as a result using the `std::string` constructor:

```
constexpr std::string(const char* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

In order to populate it with empty `string`s, simple leave the second argument out:

```
vector<T> blank(array.size());
```